# Portable FTP server for 32 bit Windows XP with no admin rights

Tags: gratis, portable, ftp, windows-xp

The title & the [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) tag say it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Baby FTP Server](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_ftp_server.html).

[image: Baby FTP Server]

> This Baby FTP server has only the most necessary features and is yet powerful enough to be a basis for a more complex server.

It's a single executable that requires no admin rights nor installation. Just download, double click and you're good to go.

Comment: A nice, neat & simple solution. No firewall configuration needed, no problems.

Answer (score 2):

So, the one I've found is called Quick`n Easy FTP Server Lite. It is pretty simple to use but does give if need quite a few advanced options. It's free and compatible with windows XP. Now, in regard to your main requirement, it *can* run without admin rights but here's what you need to know: You must allow the port to go through your router (for public use) and window's firewall itself (which *usually* requires admin rights). There is no way around the windows firewall with getting an open port without admin rights but you may not need them depending on how to firewall was setup (try and see if it works). In any case, this software should be exactly what you're looking for - it even has a XP control panel looking interface:).

## [Quick `n Easy FTP Server Lite](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/quick__n_easy_ftp_server_lite.html) (free)

> Quick `n Easy FTP Server Lite is a standalone, multi-threaded FTP server that offers advanced features and security. The interface is simple and intuitive, with organized sections for managing users, configuration...
>
> [image: FTP Server UI]

Comment: Thanks, Tom (+1). I will have to wait until Monday at the office to see how it goes. But I can tell you that I already checked and I cannot access the Windwos firewall :-(

Comment: @Mawg That sucks, I **hate** not being an admin on computers I'm working on, now if it makes a difference, it should work on the local network (I've setup like php chat scripts using applications like easyphp, and while it wouldn't be open to the public (world), they were accessible to anyone on the local network)